# How to make a running application on macos to float above other apps?

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, nsrunningapplication

I am making an application that can set a running application window to float above other apps so that if you click outside of the app's window, its window will still remain on the screen.

I have tried to use `app.activate(options: NSApplication.ActivationOptions.activateIgnoringOtherApps)` where `app` is the frontmost running application set by `app = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication`, but this method only shows the window and when you click outside the app it hides again.

```
func setAppFloating() {
        let app = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication
        app?.activate(options: NSApplication.ActivationOptions.activateIgnoringOtherApps)
    }
```

I want to set the window of the running application to Floating so that when you click outside the window, the app should still remain visible above other apps.

Comment: Are you trying to make the windows or your own app float? Or the windows of some different app? For the former, you can override the `isFloatingPanel` property in your window subclass to return true.

Comment: @KenThomases I want to set the windows of a different app to float. I knew about the floating panel property for my own app. Can you access another app's properties and modify them? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that. The AppleScript Standard Suite has a `floating` property for windows, but it's read-only. The Accessibility API reports floating-ness as a sub-role, which is not a writable attribute. There might be private Window-server functions that can do that.